# Align text at the bottom

Tags: html, css

I am not able to align text at the bottom.

```css
.container {
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 320px;
  height: 480px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  background-image: url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zumartic/calculator/master/calculator.jpg");
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
.head {
  width: 320px;
  height: 45px;
  color: yellow;
  font-size: 200%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
.display1 {
  width: 320px;
  height: 45px;
  font-size: 200%;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: -5px;
  text-align: right;
}
.display2 {
  width: 320px;
  height: 90px;
}
#D2-content {
  width: 320px;
  font-size: 200%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
  margin-left: -1px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="head" id="head">FCC Calculator</div>
  <div class="display1" id="display1"></div>
  <div class="display2" id="display2">
    <div id="D2-content">0</div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="button-item" id="CE">CE</div>
  <div class="button-item" id="C">C</div>
  <div class="button-item"></div>
  <div class="button-item"></div>
  <div class="button-item" id="7">7</div>
  <div class="button-item" id="8">8</div>
  <div class="button-item" id="9">9</div>
  <div class="button-item" id="divide">/</div>
  <div class="button-item" id="4">4</div>
  <div class="button-item" id="5">5</div>
  <div class="button-item" id="6">6</div>
  <div class="button-item" id="multiply">*</div>
  <div class="button-item" id="1">1</div>
  <div class="button-item" id="2">2</div>
  <div class="button-item" id="3">3</div>
  <div class="button-item" id="minus">-</div>
  <div class="button-item" id="0">0</div>
  <div class="button-item" id="point">.</div>
  <div class="button-item" id="equal">=</div>
  <div class="button-item" id="plus">+</div>
</div>
```

I want to align then text inside D2-content -element. I have already tried to use table and it is possible to align at bottom, but then word wrap does not work anymore. Any suggestions?

Comment: please create a snippet using the <> button in the editor. This will help others see what problem you're encountering and be better able to help you.

Answer (score 3):

Add `position:absolute` to the content which you have to move. And add `position:relative` to the parent element.

```css
.container {
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 320px;
    height: 480px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    background-image: url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zumartic/calculator/master/calculator.jpg");
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}

.head {  
    width: 320px;
    height: 45px;
    color: yellow;
    font-size: 200%;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

.display1 {  
    width: 320px;
    height: 45px; 
    font-size: 200%;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: -5px;
    text-align: right;
}

.display2 { 
    width: 320px;
    height: 90px;
    position:relative;
}

#D2-content {
    width: 320px;
    font-size: 200%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: right;
    margin-left: -1px;
    
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="head" id="head">FCC Calculator</div>
    <div class="display1" id="display1"></div>
    <div class="display2" id="display2"><div id="D2-content">0</div></div><hr>
    <div class="button-item" id="CE">CE</div>
    <div class="button-item" id="C">C</div>
    <div class="button-item"> </div>
    <div class="button-item"> </div>
    <div class="button-item" id="7">7</div>
    <div class="button-item" id="8">8</div>
    <div class="button-item" id="9">9</div>
    <div class="button-item" id="divide">/</div>
    <div class="button-item" id="4">4</div>
    <div class="button-item" id="5">5</div>
    <div class="button-item" id="6">6</div>
    <div class="button-item" id="multiply">*</div>
    <div class="button-item" id="1">1</div>
    <div class="button-item" id="2">2</div>
    <div class="button-item" id="3">3</div>
    <div class="button-item" id="minus">-</div>
    <div class="button-item" id="0">0</div>
    <div class="button-item" id="point">.</div>
    <div class="button-item" id="equal">=</div>                                         
    <div class="button-item" id="plus">+</div>
</div>
```